# cordova sqlite query rows length > 0 but items throws exception

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have a simple database that is built and filled with data, i have extracted the database from the device and examined it, it is correct, however when i query the database in with the cordova plugin(https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage), I have in the logs this:

> "{"rows":{"length":15},"rowsAffected":0}"

which indicates that the query has successfully found the records. but when i use the item function to get the results, it throws an exception, the following code is fired after the device is ready and the database is made, and filled.

```
var dataBase = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "database.sqlite"});
            dataBase.transaction(function(db) {
                db.executeSql("select * from Settings;", [], function(db, res) {
                    if(res.rows.length > 0) {
                        try{
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                            alert("RowsObject"+JSON.stringify(res.rows.item(0)));
                        }
                        catch(e){
                            alert("failed get results from query"+JSON.stringify(e));
                        }
                     }
                }, function(db, e){
                    console.log("error in sql:"+JSON.stringify(e));
                });
            });
```

Comment: The code in the question is missing the location setting which has been mandatory for almost 2 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same issue, rolled back to latest stable release and it worked again.

cordova plugin remove cordova-sqlite-storage

cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage@0.7.10

Comment: this did it thanks, do know if it is a know issue or i should add it to issue tracking?

Comment: I would not recommend this kind of solution since it would now miss 2 years of bug fixes and other important updates. In addition a couple data loss risk issues were discovered and fixed over the past year. Please see https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/441#issuecomment-361291097 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be that you are using:

```
res.row.item(0)
```

Rather than:

```
res.rows.item(0)
```

The documentation for the plugin [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) shows the expected syntax res.rows (plural) rather than res.row (singular).

Comment: yes that was a typeo when writing the question, the source uses the plural rows

Answer (score -1):

I have an interesting finding here.

If you use `"select * from Settings;"` you will get the result as you mentioned in the question and trying to access `item` will result in error.

Instead, If you use field names in the query, like, `"select field1, field2 from Settings;"` you will still get the result as you mentioned in the question, as well as, you should be able to access item.

You can access item one by one by iterating.

```
        for(var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++){
            var field1 = res.rows.item(i).field1;
            var field2 = res.rows.item(i).field2;
        }
```

I'm using **cordova-sqlite-storage** version **2.2.1**